# Combining arrays, loops and if statements

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to understand how to apply arrays, loops and if statements combined. I have created an array of weekdays and I would like to specify that on a particular day that certain exercise should be assigned. I would like to also print out the days and the exercise assigned. As you will see from the code below, using the `weekday.push()` method assigns swimming or weight training on alternate days, doesn't add yoga at all and creates 14 values. Could you please suggest how to approach this. Thanks!

```js
var weekday = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var workOut = [];

function myExercise() {
  for (var i = 0; i < weekday.length; i++) {
    if (weekday == 'Wed' || 'Mon' || 'Fri') {
      workOut.push('Swimming');
    }
    if (weekday == 'Tue' || 'Thur' || 'Sat') {
      workOut.push('weight training');
    } else {
      workOut.push('Yoga' + 'or' + 'power walking');
    }
  }
}

myExercise();
console.log(workOut);
```

Comment: Not answering your question but fyi instead of an `if` you could use a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

Comment: definitely use a switch here

Comment: not sure a switch would help in this case. You'd either need to hard code the `workOut.push()` for each day or order the cases weirdly (Mon,Wed,Fri,Tue,Thur,Sat) to overlap the cases.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is already switch statement in previous answer, but I am including this one as well. It might be not DRY, but for a beginner easier to understand:

```
var weekday = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var workOut = [];

function myExercise() {    
    for (var i = 0; i < weekday.length; i++) {
        switch(weekday[i]) {
            case 'Sun':
                workOut.push('Yoga' + 'or' + 'power walking');
                break;
            case 'Mon':
                workOut.push('Swimming');
                break;
            case 'Tue':
                workOut.push('weight training');
                break;
            case 'Wed':
                workOut.push('Swimming');
                break;
            case 'Thu':
                workOut.push('weight training');
                break;
            case 'Fri':
                workOut.push('Swimming');
                break;
            case 'Sat':
                workOut.push('weight training');
                break;
                default:
                workOut.push('Sleep!!');
        }
    }
}

myExercise();
console.log(workOut);
```

Comment: I think you should always* group cases that have the same result together, don't you agree?

Comment: Definitely I agree. But as I mentioned, this one might be easier to understand for a beginner.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you can't use the short cut like you tried in your if clause. Also you forgot the iterator `[i]`. Besides the normal

```
if (weekday[i] == 'Wed' || weekday[i] == 'Mon' ||  weekday[i] == 'Fri')
```

you could also use the following form:

```
if ( ['Wed','Mon','Fri'].includes(weekday[i]))
```

If you want to support IE (no support for [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)) you instead could work with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

This is handy whenever you want to check a lot of values. Altogether, you could write it like this:

Note, I also changed your second `if` to an `else if` (which was the reason for the 14 entries) and used the [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. Also, it is a bad habit to manipulate an object that does not belong to your scope (workout is in the global scope, but gets manipulated by the `myExercise` function). It is better to return the desired result and then do a simple assignment.

```js
var weekday = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var workOut = [];

function myExercise() {

  return weekday.map(function(day){
      var workout;
      if (['Mon','Wed','Fri'].includes(day)){
        workout = "Swimming";
      } else if (['Tue','Thur','Sat'].includes(day)){
        workout = "Weight training";
      } else {
        workout = 'Yoga or power walking';
      }
      return workout;
  });
}

workOut = myExercise();
console.log(workOut);
```

Comment: Is `includes()` widely supported?

Comment: Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=control#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I added an alternative for IE users;)

Comment: what's the point in using the extra function? Why not do workout = weekday.map(fn)

Comment: This is just resembling the code of the OP. It might come in handy later, if you want to reuse the functionality.

Comment: @Christoph: Thank you! I see that I need to study up on global and local scope :). Now I know why I was getting 14 entries.  Array.prototype.map is new to me.

Comment: @Jindi You are welcome, glad I could help! If this fixes your problem(s), you can click the check mark, to indicate to the SO community that your question has been solved. Cheers!

Comment: @Christoph: One question, why do you have "function (day)", what is the purpose of day here?

Comment: `day` refers to the element of the array, same like `workout[i]` does. Have a look at the map docu from my answer, there you can find the parameters for the callback function to be `callback(currentValue,index,array)`.

Comment: @Christoph, one more question (since you are so good at answering them ;o)). How do I print out the actual days of the week instead of the index numbers. I would like to print out the day + the exercise.

Comment: Depending on the format you want, you would return a concatenated string: `return day+": "+workout;` or an object or array like this `return [day,workout];` from the `myExercise` function. Working overtime here for you and then you accept another answer, ts;-)

Comment: @Christoph, thanks a bunch for your help! I really appreciate having people like you to help me learn.

Answer (score 1):

Modiefied your code, there was spelling mistakes and conditions were overlapped

```js
var weekday = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var workOut = [];

function myExercise() {
  for (var i = 0; i < weekday.length; i++) {
  console.log(weekday[i] )
    if (weekday[i] == 'Wed' || weekday[i] == 'Mon' || weekday[i] == 'Fri') {
      workOut.push('Swimming');
    }
    else{
    if (weekday[i] == 'Tues' || weekday[i] == 'Thur' || weekday[i] == 'Sat') {
      workOut.push('weight training');
    } else {
      workOut.push('Yoga' + 'or' + 'power walking');
    }
    }
  }
}

myExercise();
console.log(workOut);
VM280:18
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var weekdays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var workouts = weekdays.map(day => {
  switch (day) {
    case 'Wed':
    case 'Mon':
    case 'Fri':
      return 'Swimming';
      break;
    case 'Tues':
    case 'Thur':
    case 'Sat':
      return 'weight training';
      break;
    default:
      return 'Yoga or power walking';
      break;
  }
});

console.log(workouts);
```

Comment: Thanks! One question, what is the purpose of "(day)" here?

Comment: When you loop over an array using the `map` method, the function that gets called on every item within the array takes two arguments: the first one is the current item (which I called day, since the items in your weekdays array are all `day`s) and the second one is the current index. We don't need the index in our code, so I left it out. See [Array.prototype.map() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control)

The switch uses (day) to compare the cases with.
Basically: `If (day === 'Wed' || day === 'Mon' || day === 'Fri')` etc

Comment: Got it! Thanks again for your help!